# Highlight/Unhighlight ONE row in a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a pretty basic table at the moment:

[image]

I need to be able to only hightlight one row in each column, and deselect whatever was selected before it..

I understand I'm going to need a CSS class, e.g.

```
 .hightlighted {
 background: #f00;
 color: #fff;
 }
```

The HTML in the view is pretty basic also:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td>Differdange</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>       
    <tr>
<td> </td>
<td>Dippach</td>
<td> </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td>Dudelange</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td>Echternach</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td>Erpelscheid</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td>Esch-sur-Alzette</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td>Esch-sur-Sûre</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
<td> </td>
<td>Ettelbruck</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
<td> </td>
<td>Feulen</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody
```

But I don't know whether it's appropriate to highlight/unhighlight rows in CSS if I am going to be needing to 'grab' the selected data from the rows when the table is completed by the user?

Can anyone suggest what I should use (JQuery, Javascript, CSS) to highlight a row in a column so that I can get the data later?

**EDIT**

Now I've got the highlighting sorted, the only problem I'm having is differentiating between columns so that instead of this (which I'm getting atm)

[image]

I want each columns to be able to have it's own unique row highlighted (e.g. Differdange could be highlighted, as well as dddd on Localities)

Any way to edit the

```
$("tr").click(function() {
$("tr").removeClass("highlighted");
$(this).addClass("highlighted");
});
```

code to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()` jQuery methods to achieve this. Here's a little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/PBQLu/). The code is pretty self-explaining, but here's a commented version of the JavaScript part:

```
var chosen = []; //an array to save the chosen row for each column
$("td").click(function() { //when a td is clicked
    var idx = $(this).index() + 1; //get column of current cell
    $("td:nth-child(" + idx + ")").removeClass("highlighted"); //unhighlight all cells in column
    $(this).addClass("highlighted"); //highlight this one
    chosen[idx] = $(this).parent("tr").index(); //and save it as chosen in its column
});
```

Answer (score 2):

............................
***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3YYyN/7/)***

Hi now you can do this jquery as like this

**Css**

```
    .hightlighted{
 background: #f00;
 color: #fff;
 }
```

**jquery**

```
$("tr").click(function(){

    $("tr").removeClass('hightlighted')
         $(this).addClass('hightlighted');


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more precise on when and how the selection should be made? I'm guessing you want the user to click on a row, which then gets highlighted. In that case you'd want to create a highlight class in css, add it to the row the user clicked on and later you can get the row cia its class:

```
tr.highlighted td {
    background: #f0;
    color: #fff;
}
```

And in the javascript:

```
// catch click event
$('tr').click(function (e) {
    // remove prvious selection
    $('tr.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
    // make this row selected
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass('highlighted');
});

// get current selection
function getSelected () {
    return $('tr.highlighted');
}
```